# Can Hierarchical Custom Settings be used in Javascript Remoting calls?

Tags: visualforce, customsetting, javascript-remoting

Can we use JS Remoting to Fetch and update Hierarchical Custom Settings?

Also, if yes, then can we make it work as well if Custom Setting object is in Protected Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Judging by Daniel Hoechst's blog post here](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/07/25/allowing-any-user-to-edit-custom-settings/) you can access them via Javascript using remoting.

I wouldn't expect a protected setting to be visible though, and definitely not if it's protected setting inside of a managed package.

Comment: My post was more about list custom settings, but I would venture to guess you could access hierarchical settings as well since the remoting call still runs under the same user.

Comment: Assuming the code being called by remoting is in the same package as the custom setting, you would be allowing controlled access to said custom setting.

Comment: Good point @sfdcfox, if those methods are global it should work.